# Validate All or No Strings are Populated in Java

Tags: java, validation, boolean, java-stream

I have a need to validate several strings and ensure that either every single string is populated or none of them are.

I'm receiving the data, so I am not in control of it, and non-populated could be null or empty strings (Strings with just whitespace are counted as populated).

I can obviously write something like:

```
String s1 = "A";
String s2 = "B";
String s3 = "C";

boolean valid = (
        (s1 == null || s1.isEmpty()) && 
        (s2 == null || s2.isEmpty()) && 
        (s3 == null || s3.isEmpty())
    ) || (
        (s1 != null && !s1.isEmpty()) && 
        (s2 != null && !s2.isEmpty()) && 
        (s3 != null && !s3.isEmpty())
);
```

but that is getting hard to read and I think there are going to end up being seven strings I need to check.

so I started looking at streams and I can do

```
boolean anyPopulated = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3).anyMatch(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty());
boolean allPopulated = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3).allMatch(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty());
boolean valid = (anyPopulated == allPopulated);
```

Which is a bit easier to read but I can't help thinking there must be an easier way to do this that is readable.

I need to use standard Java for this so no libraries.

Comment: StringUtils.isEmpty(myVar) comes to mind, might even be there's a version of it that takes an array or a List, don't really know. Try not to re-invent the wheel, use those already around

Comment: @stultuske a client policy means I cannot use third party libraries here

Comment: so, you're also not going to use the JDK, since you didn't write that?

Comment: Stuff them in a list, create a for loop increase a counter for each filled or nulled element. In the end 1 should be 0 and the other should be the size of the list. If not error. Just noticed that was already proposed as an answer with a Stream solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least only one stream involved

```
public static boolean validate(String... strings) {
    long populated = Stream.of(strings).filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty()).count();
    return populated == 0 || populated == strings.length;
}
```

Comment: I think this is an elegant, as it does not materialize any element, but instead simply counts them.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank you for appreciating this solution. But I have a vague feeling that there are more succinct ones, it just hasn't occurred to me

Comment: The only way I could think of is using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`: `filter(StringUtils::isEmpty)`.

Comment: Actually I thought the same. The method reference fits very nice here, but OP wants no libraries

Answer (score 2):

## allMatch() + noneMatch()

Regarding your stream-based solution, you would advise using a combination `allMatch()` + `noneMatch()` and `allPopulated || nonePopulated`.

Condition `allPopulated || nonePopulated` is more intuitive than `anyPopulated == allPopulated` and requires less effort to read.

It might look like there are two iterations, but keep in mind that operations `allMatch()` and `noneMatch()` are *short circuit* and therefore none of the two streams would iterate over the whole data set.

```
boolean nonePopulated = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3)
    .noneMatch(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty());
boolean allPopulated = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3)
    .allMatch(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty());

boolean valid = allPopulated || nonePopulated;
```

**Note** that also possible to keep the solution **short-circuit** and utilize only a single stream. To understand the logic, let's first have a look at the implementation with a plain `for`-loop.

## Short-circuit solution - For-loop

To implement short-circuit logic using a loop, we can evaluate the predicate for the very first element and check all subsequent outcomes against the base result. After the first outcome that doesn't match base one, we can break the loop.

```
boolean isValid = validateAll(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty(), s1, s2, s3);
```

```
public static <T> boolean validateAll(Predicate<T> pred, T... args) {
    
    if (args.length == 0) return true; // or throw

    boolean base = pred.test(args[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (base != pred.test(args[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

## Short-circuit solution - A single Stream

Similarly to the previous solution, we can start with evaluating the predicate for the first element. But instead of storing the result, we can adjust the predicate itself and further apply either negated predicated or initial predicate.

This stream can terminate starting from the second element (*if the data is invalid*).

```
public static <T> boolean validateAll(Predicate<T> pred, T... args) {
    
    if (args.length == 0) return true; // or throw

    Predicate<T> adjustedPredicate = pred.test(args[0]) ? pred : pred.negate();

    return Arrays.stream(args).skip(1).allMatch(adjustedPredicate);
}
```

There are options on how to perform this validation using a single stream, and even one statement. Some of them are listed below, but that they are not short-circuit, less space-efficient and require more effort to read.

## Single statement - Built-in Collectors

Here's a solution based on the combination of collectors [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) and [`partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)) that would allow obtaining `isValid` value in a single statement:

```
boolean isValid = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty(),
            Collectors.counting()),
        map -> map.get(true) == 0 || map.get(false) == 0
    ));
```

## One stream - Custom Collector

If we generalize the task, it can be tackled using a *custom collector*, which makes uses a boolean array as the accumulation type (similar approaches you can in implementation's of built-in collectors from the `Collectors` class).

To create a *custom collector*, we can make use of the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

```
boolean isValid = validateAll(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty(), s1, s2, s3);
```

Generic method, which expects a *varargs* of `T` and a `Predicate<T>`:

```
public static <T> boolean validateAll(Predicate<T> pred, T... args) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(args).collect(allMatchOrNoneMatch(pred));
}
```

A *custom collector*, which produces a `boolean` value:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Boolean> allMatchOrNoneMatch(Predicate<T> pred) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new Boolean[]{null, true},
        (Boolean[] arr, T next) -> {
            if (arr[0] == null) arr[0] = pred.test(next);
            else if (arr[1] && (pred.test(next) != arr[0])) arr[1] = false;
        },
        (left, right) -> {
            left[1] = left[1] && right[1];
            return left;
        },
        arr -> arr[1]
    );
}
```

Comment: wrong, `anyMatch` and `allMatch`, as posted in question are fine

Comment: why is it not fine, try it, or give a counter-example - note the result is `anyPopulated == allPopulated`  (maybe be using `noneMatch` and `||` is easier to understand)

Comment: @Jameson_uk Correct, but the latter is more readable.

Comment: True that both `allMatch` and `noneMatch` will short-circuit. However, if you have 100 strings, all blank except the 50th string, then _both_ will traverse the first 50 strings before both returning `false`. Hence you will iterate 50 strings twice. With a simple `for` loop, you can do it in one iteration. How can you do this in a functional way (e.g. using streams)?

Comment: @k314 BTW "*both* will traverse the first 50 strings" is not correct: `allMatch` will stop at the first blank string - in your example the very first one - since `...&& !s.isEmpty` will not match - "How can you do this in a functional way (e.g. using streams)?" -> see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974097/16320675)

Comment: @user16320675 you're right, only one stream will iterate. In that case, I favour this solution (using the two streams, with only one actually iterating). The other solution uses a single stream, but always iterates the whole stream and checks every single string, when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from Alexander Ivanchenko's excellent answer, I would like to shorten it slightly by inverting the condition so it checks for all or none empty (which gives the same results) and putting it into a method:

```
private static boolean allOrNonePopulated(String... strings) {
    return Stream.of(strings).allMatch(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty())
        || Stream.of(strings).noneMatch(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty());
}
```